# Display images in masterpage on first time IIS default document is called

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, redirect

I got a solution with main page (`Default.aspx)` at this location `"D:\Websites\wwwFlofab\HomeSite\Default\Pages"` that is using a master page (`Site.Master`) at this location `"D:\Websites\wwwFlofab\HomeSite\Master\Pages"`.

When accessing our website we were using a `Default.aspx` (not the one mentioned above) to redirect to my `Default.aspx`. That way, when I was typing our url, it was redirecting so instead of getting `"http://www.mywebsite.com"` I was having something like `"http://www.mywebsite.com/HomeSite/Default/Pages/Default.aspx"`

I didn't liked the `"/HomeSite/Default/Pages/Default.aspx"` to be shown at first loading so I changed my IIS 7.5 default document to `"Default/Pages/Default.aspx"` to avoid a redirect.

It's now correctly displayed on first load (`http://www.mywebsite.com`).

Then I saw something that I do not understand and that's why I'm posting here :)

In my master page, I was having many images that were displayed like this

```
<img src='~/Styles/images/ASME.png' />
```

After that IIS default document changed, all these images (in master page) were not showing up (on first load only). To display them correctly, I need to add our url.

```
<img src='http://www.mywebsite.com/HomeSite/Styles/images/ASME.png' />
```

Why would my images display correctly on a manual redirect and not when it's called from IIS?

It's the same page, same folders, only the url changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the "~" sign in your image path but didn't add `runat="server"` so the path was sent as is to the client.

The client took your image path and combined it with the url of the page address, so `"http://www.mywebsite.com/HomeSite/Default/Pages/Default.aspx"` and `'~/Styles/images/ASME.png'` resolved in `"http://www.mywebsite.com/HomeSite/Styles/images/ASME.png"`, but when the address is only the host name, then the image url will result in `"http://www.mywebsite.com/Styles/images/ASME.png"`.

The way to solve it is to add `runat="server"` to the image, so the server will resolve the correct client url in any case.

```
<img runat="server" src='~/Styles/images/ASME.png' />
```

Comment: But what should I do to include <script>.
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/Styles/Site.css" /> work correctly because '~' is replaced by HomeSite, but in <script> this is not working. '~' looks to be interpreted as text

Comment: Add runat=server in any place you have server path, including script.

Comment: didn't know I could put runat="server" on scripts, thanks again